# R data.table - most frequent combinations of column values including subtotals

Tags: r, data.table

I have an R data.table with several (up to 30) integer columns and would like to find the top frequent combinations of their values, including subtotals.

This code works:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1107)

dt<-data.table(col1=sample(1:10,1000,TRUE),col2=sample(1:20,1000,TRUE),col3=sample(1:5,1000,TRUE),col4=sample(1:15,1000,TRUE),col5=sample(1:33,1000,TRUE))
group_vars<-c('col1','col2','col3','col4','col5')
dt_cube<-cube(dt,.(N=.N),by=group_vars)
dt_cube[order(-1*N)][1:5,]
```

And provides an output like this:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5    N
1:   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 1000
2:   NA   NA    3   NA   NA  210
3:   NA   NA    1   NA   NA  209
4:   NA   NA    5   NA   NA  198
5:   NA   NA    2   NA   NA  197
```

The problem is that the real data are very large and the whole cube cannot be computed. I am interested in the top 100 most frequent combinations (including subtotals). Is there any way how to get it without producing the whole cube?

Comment: You mention *"including subtotals"* a couple of times but your code calculates no sums and it isn't obvious (to me) what you mean by that. Can you explain that some more, please?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the subtotals produced by cube - e.g. the very first row in the output is the grand total (all values of col1 & all values of col2 & ...), the second row is subtotal having 3 in col3 and any values in the remaining columns and so on.

Comment: Could you generate a table with top 100 results before cube() it? Like    dt_top100 <- dt[, .N, by=group_vars][order(-N)][1:100]    then cube(dt_top100,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's memory efficiency and time efficiency.  If we're not memory constrained then we usually want the approach that takes the least time.  In your case, you're memory constrained (I'm guessing that's why you can't run cube on your full data set) and have to give up on speed efficiency, after all cube is returning 16000+ rows when you only want 5.

Try this:

```
top_combos<-5 #change this to whatever number you want, ie 100

endsummary<-data.table(N=rep(0,top_combos))
for(col in group_vars) endsummary[,(col):=as.integer(NA)]

for(i in 0:length(group_vars)) {
  j<-combn(group_vars, i)
  for(k in 1:ncol(j)) {
    sub_dt<-dt[,.N,by=eval(j[,k])][order(-N)]
    for(l in setdiff(group_vars, j[,k])) sub_dt[,(l):=as.integer(NA)]
    endsummary<-rbindlist(list(endsummary, sub_dt),use.names=TRUE)[order(-N)][1:top_combos]
  }
}
endsummary
```

It essentially does what cube does but doesn't retain anything unless it's a higher count than whatever it has previously counted.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But on large data it is actually slower than the cube.

Comment: Well yeah I didn't expect it to be faster. Your stated problem was that your data is too large for cube to work